# printing the both values on the same line java

Tags: java

code:

```
public class Aeroplane {

    private String name;
    private Coordinates coordinates;
    private int speed;
    private int totalDistance; 
    private int repairDistance;


    public Aeroplane(String name, int xcoordinate, int ycoordinate, int speed, int totalDistance, int repairDistance)    {                                                     
            this.name= name;                  
            coordinates=new Coordinates(xcoordinate,ycoordinate);
            this.speed=speed;
            this.totalDistance = totalDistance;
            this.repairDistance= repairDistance;         
    }


    public void singleFlight(Destination destination  ) {

        // Some temp vars to hold 
        int tempX=0;
        int tempY=0;



        // Hold current x,y coordinates
        int currentX=coordinates.getXCoordinate(); // Get X coordinate from plane coord object
        int currentY=coordinates.getYCoordinate(); // Get Y coord

        // Hold the Desinationation coordinates -
        int destinationX=destination.getXCoordinate();
        int destinationY=destination.getYCoordinate();


        // Print Start Coordinates here

        System.out.println(currentX);
        System.out.println(currentY);


        // While loop
        while(currentX!=destinationX || currentY!=destinationY) // So as long as either the x,y coord of the current
        // planes position do not equal the destination coord, then keep going
        {

            // Get difference btn currentX and destination
            tempX=destinationX-currentX;
            if (tempX<speed) {              
                currentX+=speed; // Increment current position by speed
            }
            else{
                currentX+=tempX; // Increment speed by remaining distance. 
            }

            // Same for y coord
            tempY=destinationY-currentY;
            if (tempY<speed) {
                currentY+=speed;
            }
            else    {
                currentY+=tempY;
            }

            // Print current x, y coord here


        }

        // Print final destionation here

    }


    public void setname (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getname() {
        return name; 
    }

}
```

how do i the alter the println to make the two prints on the same, line.?

```
int currentX=coordinates.getXCoordinate(); 
int currentY=coordinates.getYCoordinate();

System.out.println(currentX);
System.out.printlncurrentY);
```

so instead of x and then y on the next line, i want x, y on the same line.

Comment: Did you look at the other functions in `System.out`?

Comment: what about concatenation of strings within a single `println()` call?

Answer (score 0):

use `System.out.print()` for printing cordinate X and then use `System.out.println()` to print cordinate Y

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `println` means 'print line'.  Each time you use this, Java will start on a new line in console.

If you don't want it to start on a new line each time, you can just use `System.out.print()`.  Java will then print both out on the same line.

```
System.out.print(currentX);
System.out.print(currentY);
```

Alternatively, you can also just run one `println` statement for both variables:

```
System.out.println("Current X: " + currentX + "; Current Y: " + currentY);
```

And it will all print out on one line.